# Update the context variable based on the return JSON

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need to update the JSON of a node in watson assistant based on the JSON that returns from my API.

Example: A node of my assistant has a response that shows a list of options, JSON below creates that list of options.

```
{"output": { "generic": [ { "title": "aaaaa", "options": [ { "label": "aaaaa", "value": { "input": { "text": "a" } } }, { "label": "bbbbb", "value": { "input": { "text": "b" } } } ], "response_type": "option" } ] } }
```

I need to change this JSON and put in it the JSON that comes from my API, example of JSON is below.

```
{"output": { "generic": [ { "title": "Relação de Cidades", "options": [ { "label": "São Paulo", "value": { "input": { "text": "SP" } } }, { "label": "Rio de janeiro", "value": { "input": { "text": "RJ" } } }, { "label": "Bahia", "value": { "input": { "text": "BA" } } } ], "response_type": "option" } ] }, "context": {} }
```

Or could I send this JSON that returns from the API straight into the conversation in such a way that it assembles the list of options that JSON creates ...?

I've tried to put this JSON in a variable and show the content of that variable in the conversation, but it shows the content of the JSON instead of assembling the list that JSON defines.

The result follows. I did it like this:

[image]

I appreciate any help, as I did not find any material on the Internet that would help me solve this.

Comment: Is this to be a permanent update, or just an update for this run, and you want to  revert back to the original output. You can modify nodes using the V1 API, but these are permanent changes.

Comment: This will happen every time that the Node is reached.

Comment: I am not sure I am following. Are you saying that you want to update the node every time it is visited. ie. 1st time 'A', 2nd 'B', 3rd 'C' etc. Does the modified output depend on what it is trying to output, or is it independent?  If so then why not invoke a cloud function instead of having the node return anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can just return this as a context variable and then quote that context variable inside another context variable.

Set the customisation that you want as $Variable1

then inside your context variable just specify the value as $Variable1